# create regions of code

Tags: c#, groovy, intellij-idea, region

I am coming from C# where we can create regions of code (Which I love) such as

```
#region MyCodeIsHere
//code
#endregion
```

So I can hide large chunks of code that work.  Is there an equivalent way to do this in groovy?

Comment: You do know that `#region` is part of the C# language? It is in the spec (section 2.5.6 in version 5.0 of the spec).

Comment: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/

Comment: Define "large chunks." I'm worried. :S I'm on a legacy app where prior developers abused regions like mad, instead of refactoring to smaller methods and classes where "hiding code" becomes unnecessary.

Comment: "folding used to sweep code under the rug" is a bad thing.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html

Comment: I don't think its a bad thing, it helps to organize code and methods.  It is not a replacement for refactoring which it sounds like is the fear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ofstream, seems I can do it in intellij which is what I am using:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/